# NLTK: How to filter stopwords and do stemming on N-gram tokens?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I have currently following pipe:

1) Text -> `from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize` -> unigram tokens ['word1', 'word2', ..]

2) Filter unigram tokens on `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` and do stemming on each word

3) Get PoS from filtered unigram words

4) Get NE

But I want to handle N-gram tokens which are more informative, but confused when I should filter tokens from garbage AKA `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` + my own unigram stopwords and normalize words with stemming. Please advise:

1) Text -> Sentence Tokenizer = N-gram tokens

2) N-gram tokens -> PoS -> Named Entities

3) N-gram tokens -> Classification

Comment: Optimization-related questions are best asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). They are generally considered off-topic here.

Comment: Btw, in terms of tagging quality, you shouldn't do PoS tagging on individual tokens, but on sequences, *including* stop words. Also, NLTK's default PoS tagger isn't trained on stemmed words, so you should do this afterwards.

Comment: @lenz, thanks for reply and sorry for being late. I've update the question related to NLTK, could you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what your question is here. However, I still think you should PoS-tag the plain, tokenised text before stemming and filtering. Also, I suggest you take the n-grams from the tagged sequence (including NE tags), there's no use in tagging individual n-grams separately.